# How to close exe "softly" in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I tryed to write a batch file to open a amd wraith CPU cooler LED file and close it after some seconds. 
The batch opens a file that automatically opens the cooler master software and load the settings inside this file (its like an import file that opens its program). At this moment, there are no LEDs activated but when I close the cooler master software manually, the LEDs turn on. 
My problem is that when I start the batch file, the other file is executed and the cooler master software starts but when it force closes the LEDs dont show up. I think this happens from the force close of the exe.
Is there a way to kill the cooler master window so the settings will be saved?

```
@ECHO OFF
start /MAX C:\Users\Marvin\Documents\cpu.SR4
timeout /t 10
wmic process where name="Wraith Prism.exe" call terminate
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with:

```
taskkill /IM "Wraith Prism.exe"
```